# Set Windows 10 "Automatically show the touch keyboard" with WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, programmatically-created, on-screen-keyboard

I need to programatically enable/disable the `Automatically show the touch keyboard` option in Windows 10 with a WPF (not a UWP) like is shown [here](https://superuser.com/questions/948787/the-windows-10-onscreen-keyboard-does-not-launch-automatically%20%22%22).

I couldn't find anything. Is there any API I can use from C# or registry key I can modify to enable/disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using `Process Monitor` as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144472/1335209) answer to detect what registry value was being modified while changing the setting. So to enable/disable the `Automatically show the touch keyboard` option the registry value you have to change:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke
```

With a simple command you can enable/disable this:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7" /v EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke /t REG_WORD /d 1 /f
```

Just change between 1 and 0 to enable/disable it.

Comment: In my application the Tabtip stops showing up after some time. I wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929255/unable-to-launch-onscreen-keyboard-osk-exe-from-a-32-bit-process-on-win7-x64), you can launch the On Screen Keyboard (OSK) via the code-behind:

```
    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("osk.exe");
    }
```

I tried and tested it with a simple text box and it worked fine.  There was [another post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e9252bb7-1df0-4826-880f-ad0a636a18cd/error-when-opening-onscreen-keyboard-in-windows-7-could-not-start-onscreen-keyboard?forum=vbgeneral) that complain about the "Cannot start On-Screen Keyboard" but there was not a clear consensus.

If you need a registry setting, there seems to be one, but might not work pragmatically.  The details of the registry setting [is in this post.](http://www.technipages.com/enable-disable-on-screen-keyboard)

Comment: I don't need the show On Screen Keyboard I basically need to be able to change the Windows settings of the keyboard programatically